# Mimic var_dump//exit behavior - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, abort, var-dump

After some related issues on this site, I am trying to debug my ror code, using puts YAML::dump(object) in some lien of my controller (trying to mimic the var_dump() behavior). But I see no output in my chrome's console. Btw, if
I add `puts YAML::dump(object) abort('message')` (trying to mimic the var_dump() behavior), I don't get any output too (I have an error page but no trace of my object's dump). How to do that